# Publicly available data

Tags: dataset, open-source

I have some research data (around 300 GB) I want to make publicly available for other researchers.

Do you know where can I upload these data?

Comment: Often, university libraries have some offer for sharing data. Some even will assign a DOI to your data set, to make it easy to cite and give/receive credit - this will then be included in some citation counts, such as Google Scholar.

Comment: This question would be much more appropriate at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here:  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

They have the largest public data repository for ML that I know.